# What's the difference between $('#formID').submit and $('#formID')[0].submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here's a stripped version of an example project:

HTML:

```
<form id="formID">

    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {

    // Method 1
    // $('#formID').submit();

    // Method 2
    $('#formID')[0].submit();

}
```

In a more complicated version, Method 2 works whereas Method 1 doesn't so I'm trying to understand the difference. Method 1 does work however, when I comment out bootstrap validation.

Comment: It does work, apart from minor syntax errors you have - calling `$('#formID')[0].submit()` does work the same way `$('#formID').submit()` works. The only difference is that you're getting the `HTMLFormElement`/Node using `[0]` on a jQuery object where natively there's a `submit` function for Form Elements.

Comment: If it *doesn't* work for you, you need to provide a [MCVE] so we can see what's going wrong

Comment: I've made this code as minimal as possible, just to understand the difference between the two. However, I do have a project where the second method works and the first doesn't.

Comment: @Xander, This code works for Method1 also, probably in your project it may be returning with some errors. Did you checked the console?

Comment: @mbharanidharan88 No console errors, whilst using Method 1, nothing happens when the input button is clicked. If I use Method 2 everything works perfectly and all form data is sent to the Java servlet etc.

Comment: Here's a [MCVE](http://jsfiddle.net/65rjLp7w/) proving that this works. Error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Xander, ok as a quick debugging, open console and try this please ` $('#formID')`. If this return form element and if no console error then it should work

Comment: Without an actual [MCVE] for the question, it would appear to be off-topic

Comment: @mbharanidharan88 The form element returns correctly, yet doesn't submit using method 1.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The question is asking for an explanation of the difference between the two, not a solution to a specific problem.

Comment: If it's relevant, the form in question also has a lot of bootstrap validation applied to it.

Comment: The code in the question does not result in the problem described - without being able to reproduce the problem, potential answerers will only be *guessing* at what your underlying problem actually is. (Best to avoid that, and to post a [MCVE] instead - ideally, *when you post your question*)

Comment: @Xander The question actually asks `Why does method 2 work, whilst method 1 doesn't?`, so CertainPerformance is correct.

Comment: Description edited to please pedantic users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#formID')` will give you an array like object matching all DOM elements while `$('#formID')[0]` will give you first DOM element from the object.

> By appending [0] to the jQuery object will return the first DOM
>   element.

**In your case, both functions will work perfectly and submit the same DOM Element that is form element**

You can read more details here :
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Comment: Is the form the first element? When I use console.log($('#formID')) I get this https://gyazo.com/dad90dee1eae26d76ff46f3d4dd42df9 It looks like the first element is a hidden submit button. (I didn't put it there)

Comment: No, it returns the form DOMElement. Submit button is the child element. While `[0]` or `.get()` function returns element from the same level.